# Cutting and pasting files

Tags: macos, finder, uti

OS X doesn't allow me to cut files. Are there any applications to enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can pay some you can use [Moveaddict](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/moveaddict.html):

[image]

And also I found "[this solution](http://lifehacker.com/5622046/cut-and-paste-files-in-os-xs-finder-with-automator-services)" but I didn't test it myself.

Comment: Why buy something that you can do with the operating system?

Comment: @walker can you please tell how can we cut&paste file with keyboard short cut?

Comment: If you're on Lion, @JoelPurra's answer works.

Comment: @walker when this question asked Casabash used Snow leopard dude

Comment: Ah I didn't notice the date - my mistake.

Answer (score 7):

It *is possible* to cut-paste files/folders in OSX 10.7 Lion's Finder (so, since 2011), but the OSX way is *slightly* different from the Windows way.

1. <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> (copy first)
2. <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> (now *move* to it's destination)

So, the steps are very similar to copy-paste, but holding <kbd>⌥</kbd> (option key) moves the file/folder instead of copies it.

You can also have a look in the edit menu after copying a file - press <kbd>⌥</kbd> while looking to see the difference: "paste" changes to "move item here".

Comment: Of course, this also works on Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion.

Comment: Of course, this also works on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks.

Comment: Of course, this also works on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite.

Comment: Of course, this also works on Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

[Path Finder](http://www.cocoatech.com/) supports cutting & pasting files, though I can't think of a case where I'd want to cut & paste that drag & drop wouldn't work.

Comment: some people highly prefer the keyboard :P

Answer (score -2):

You can't cut files, but you can:

1. Copy the existing file <kbd>⌘C</kbd>
2. Delete the existing file <kbd>⌘⌫</kbd>
3. Paste in the new location <kbd>⌘V</kbd>

Given that anything you can do with keystrokes can be done by AppleScript, all you would have to do is combine the first two to give you the equivalent of Cut (although you might want to have the script pause a bit between the two…).

Comment: I'm sorry, but **this doesn't work**, now that I actually tried it. What happens is you get [this error message](http://i.imgur.com/fkf6D.png). You'd have to paste first and then delete, which is much clumsier. (I'd change my +1 to -1 as this is very misleading right now, but the platform has locked the vote. I can't even edit answers here yet, due to low rep.)

Comment: Jonik - Well, drat. I tried 1-2 and 1-3, and they both worked fine, so I jumped to the conclusion that 1-2-3 would as well. Sounds like the way to go is to script the above in 1-3-2 order.

Comment: I don't think this is a sound way to go about cutting and pasting, whether it works consistently or not, as it leaves an error space where you may delete the file and not paste. @JoelPurra's works nicely - just like cut and paste on Windows, but with an extra key.